# Making stillsuits less fantasy - how to dump the heat?

Tags: technology, hard-science, deserts, future

As we all know<sup>1</sup>, stillsuit as described in the books would cook the user. Water would carry heat away from the body, but then it would be caught again, and again with the heat.

Assuming energy is not a problem in a world with tiny Hunter-seekers and routinely levitating lamps, we could probably put that heat away - but where to? Modern day phase change cooling requires either frozen packets for heat to go to, or radiators and environment colder than the user. Electrical heat pumps can heat one end to cool the other, but the heated end still needs effective way to dump the heat. Something with large thermal capacity, or radiator with airflow.

Is there anywhere we can dump heat on the Arrakis-like environment without making users look like hedgehod with glowing red fins of a radiator? And preferably with little or no moving parts?

---

<sup>1</sup> [The Science of Dune: An Unauthorized Exploration into the Real Science](https://books.google.pl/books?id=4kbYExSCa6oC&pg=PT149&lpg=PT149&dq=stillsuit+dune+cooking+user&source=bl&ots=NABugE1r4D&sig=ACfU3U0TzgyCfvV1ZxgX5LmdLJT7h2xO7g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjjKaTsfnzAhVvo4sKHVrvAjsQ6AF6BAgzEAM#v=onepage&q=stillsuit%20dune%20cooking%20user&f=false)

Comment: Refrigerators exist. Haven't read Dune. How hot is Arrakis exactly? If it's less than a hundred degrees C you can probably get by with souped-up refrigerators and they won't glow red hot.

Comment: @user253751 up to 75 degrees Celsius, but sources differ on that. And my refrigerator has about 1.5 square meter of a radiator, impractical on a suit.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments. Use comments only to ask clarification/suggest improvements to the post. Other comments will be deleted without notice

Comment: @ZeissIkon "a human body has coincidentally close to 1.5 square meters of surface area" flexible and mobile, while resisting pressure (fridges use a compressor) is hard to come with in today's level of tech. Be it only because those flexible tubes have a tendency to become rigid under pressure - works a treat for car tires.

Comment: You are in air. Just transfer excess heat to air, which is then dumped. This requires a power source, of course, but you could make the suit surface photovoltaic, no problem.

Comment: First thing is they'd need to be either white or mirrored so that they would stop absorbing radiant energy from their sun.

Answer (score 21):

If you want a Dune "hard science" answer, the "heat exchange filaments" that [AcePL gracefully cited](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/216658/26061) are very likely engineered by applying the [Holzman effect](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/216658/26061) at molecular scale. After all, repealing "fast moving atoms/molecules" and letting only the slow one pass through sounds pretty much what a Maxwell daemon would do - at ambient temperature, the nitrogen and oxygen molecules average speed is 300-400 m/s. Dial the allowed speed to lower values and the molecules allowed to pass through will be grateful for a little bit of warming up.

---

If you want real world hard science, **a heat pump and a radiator is all you need**.
[The best coefficient of performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_performance#Theoretical_performance_limits) for real world systems pumping heat from 0C to 35C is 4.5 - that is, for every Joule that you spend on the heat pump, you move 4.5J of heat from low temperature to high temperature.

The maximum theoretical achievable for cooling between 37C (310K) as the "cold temperature" and, say, 80C as the hot temperature is

$$COP_{cooling} = \frac{T_c}{T_h - T_c} = 310/47 = 6.6$$

But even only half of that would be enough, because... [human power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_power#Available_power) is not *that* big

> Normal human metabolism produces heat at a basal metabolic rate of around 80 watts.
>
> During a bicycle race, an elite cyclist can produce close to 400 watts of mechanical power over an hour and in short bursts over double that—1000 to 1100 watts; modern racing bicycles have greater than 95% mechanical efficiency. An adult of good fitness is more likely to average between 50 and 150 watts for an hour of vigorous exercise. Over an 8-hour work shift, an average, healthy, well-fed and motivated manual laborer may sustain an output of around 75 watts of power.

Assuming the freemen are trained and motivated by survival, one can allow for 150W. <strike>At a $COP_{cooling} = 3.3$, the heat pump will require a 46W - letting the freeman $150W - 46W = 104W$ of power for survival. (to compensate, the spice in the freeman's ration will need to provide 4.3 MJ for each 8 hours of marching)</strike>

@AlexP (thanks) points out in comments that the human body is not very efficient (and provides [citation for it](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Conceptual_Physics/Book%3A_Body_Physics_-_Motion_to_Metabolism_(Davis)/10%3A_Powering_the_Body/10.09%3A_Efficiency_of_the_Human_Body)), for every Joule of useful power it produces, another 2 or 3 Joules are wasted as heat (efficiency in the 25-33%). So the correction to the energy the spice ration should provide - between 12.9 MJ and 17.2MJ
More important, the heat pump will need to reject 450-600W - I'll come to it later.

The [median energy intake for athletes during competition](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5084025/) is 8674 kJ, but the extreme include a whooping 18,009 kJ (so the 8h energetic effort/day is plausible).

---

Now, the realization of the stillsuit:

1. the [lithium-ion battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery) has an energy density of 0.90–2.43 MJ/L. So 8L worth of battery (say, 12kg including well engineered electrodes and enclosure?) would let the freeman use her/his full power (and "just carry" the stillsuit, baterry pack included). After all, those Holzman shield do need some power, and they carry one even if they don't use it when navigating open sands;
2. will definitely need an insulating material, very likely reflective - the outside appearance should be like those emergency thermal blankets.
3. the trick is... if you maintain the body temperature at 36.5C, the body has little incentive to perspire. So... actually... the still suit will only condense the respiration water and extract the water in urine/fecals?
4. the radiator (air cooled) will make probably the bulk of extra weight. Because rejecting heat **must** be done by compressing the refrigeration fluid, so one expects a good heat conductor and good behavior under pressure. Probably aluminium would be good enough a compromise, otherwise one would suggest the heavier copper

Well engineered and tested in Arrakis conditions, one on top of the other (suit, compressor, radiator, battery pack) would contribute - feeling of guts - at about 20-25kg?

**To be noted that a 200W camping fridge**, able to cool 50L+ of drinks to 4C, [weights about 20kg *when empty*](https://www.4wdsupacentre.com.au/products/fridges-coolers/75l-fridge-freezer-combos-deals/kings-75l-dual-zone-fridge-freezer-adventure-kings-200w-solar-blanket-with-mppt.html).
*A 200W with an assumed $COP_{cooling} = 3.3$ would be able to reject 660W, so we are well within the reach of today's technologies*

Now, about the weight of the suit, [some perspective](https://www.cnas.org/publications/reports/the-soldiers-heavy-load-1)

> For the last 3,000 years, dismounted soldiers carried 55 to 60 pounds on average. This has almost doubled in the last 200 years. Roman legionnaires carried almost 60 pounds. The British fighting in the American Revolutionary War carried 80 pounds. At the Battle of Waterloo (1815), the British carried 60 to 70 pounds while the French carried 55 pounds. The French in the Crimean War (1853-1856) carried 72 pounds. Around World War I, approximate march weights jumped to 85 pounds. U.S. soldiers trained with at least 60 pounds but carried additional rations and munitions in combat. During World War II, U.S. troops carried more than 80 pounds in the Normandy landings. U.S. soldier loads increased even more dramatically in the second half of the 20th century. March loads stayed at approximately 80 pounds during Vietnam but grew to 100 pounds afterward, with a maximum march weight over 160 pounds in Grenada in 1983. In Iraq and Afghanistan, march weights have approximated 100 pounds or more.

---

**Answers to grumblings**

- but I'm fitter than a fit freeman and I used to push 220W for 1h

Well then, you maxed out your heat pump capacity, you probably need to do it at a higher temperature - which, BTW, is a self limiting factor - but you still won't boil inside.

An increase in $T_c$ (i.e. acceptable body temperature) will make the COP of the heat pump higher - as it only needs to fight a low temperature differential. The human body will work at 40C, a temperature when the theoretical COP goes to $COP_{cooling} = \frac{313}{353 - 313} = 7.11$ (353K is 80C, 313K is 40C). Half of that is 3.5, with a 200W input, you'll be able to reject 700W.

It's very much like what happens when you max out your A/C and then you decide to put something in the oven - you home won't catch fire, you'll just need to accept an increased kitchen temperature. You may accept it or else you will need to be wise and shut down to oven.

Comment: To produce 150 W of mechanical power, a human's metabolism will produce some 300 to 400 W of waste heat, *in addition* to the 100 W baseload. Humans are very inefficient when used as engines.

Comment: @AlexP Citation please. I'm not saying that's not true, but... `hard-science`. I can adjust the answer, but I think I'd be still safe, given that 200W camping fridge would manage to move, with a COP of 3.3, 660W - one would think that may be enough.

Comment: I'm not saying that it isn't enough. It was just a note that the numbers are on the very optimistic side, and in practice you would need more refrigeration. As for the efficiency of converting food calories into mechanical output, that's not hard to find. The generally accepted value range for [human-as-engine efficiency](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Conceptual_Physics/Book%3A_Body_Physics_-_Motion_to_Metabolism_(Davis)/10%3A_Powering_the_Body/10.09%3A_Efficiency_of_the_Human_Body) is 20% to 30%.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks, mate.

Comment: An explanation which uses the Holtzman effect can't work for the Stillsuit, because the Sandworms would show up to eat you. They hate shields and other Holtzman tech with a passion.

Comment: @10ebbor10 "sandworms...  hate shields". True... when manifested in external form. I assert that the "heat exchange filaments" work so that the field lines close inside the stillsuit, very much like the magnetic field lines never leave a ferrite core until fully saturated.

Comment: In parts of our world with conditions similar to Arrakis the solar radiation peaks at around 1000W/m^2.  Even at only 20% efficiency that's 200W.  Average torso surface area for an adult male human is just under 2m^2, figure half of that for sun exposure.  Seems like if you could get your solar efficiency to 40% the suit could just be self-powered.

Comment: "An adult of good fitness is more likely to average between 50 and 150 watts for an hour of vigorous exercise" - that's a little on the low side, when I was fit my FTP (sustained power for one hour) was between 180 and 220 and I was fairly average, much fitter cyclists can easily exceed that. Plus as @AlexP mentions, you produce at least twice that again in waste heat, ask anyone who uses Zwift inside.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth now do it for 8h and think if it makes sense, _in Arrakis_ conditions, to spend your energy in 1h when you know you have a whole day in front of you. Besides, a "good fitness" implies an increased efficiency - I'd bet to a 30% - in which case 220Wx3 = 660W - towards the limit of a 200W heat pump with a 3.3. COP, but it will hold.

Answer (score 5):

Let's find out the scale of the problem. How much heat do we actually have to dump?

[Some random source suggests](https://www.bestheating.com/info/was-morpheus-right-how-hot-are-humans/) an active human produces around 1Kw at peak output. Our stillsuit needs a refrigeration system able dump that amount of thermal energy (1000 joules per second). Assuming a perfectly passive radiator (radiates purely through, uh, radiation) we can now grab the [Stefan-Boltzman law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law)

```
P = A * ε * σ * T^4

Where:

P = power in watts to dissapate
A = area of radiator
ε = Emissivity. Lets assume a perfect black body aka 1.0
σ = 5.670373×10-8 = Stefan-Boltzmann constant
T = Temperature raise above ambient
```

We can now find the relationship between the radiator area and temperature rise:

```
A * T^4 = P / (ε * σ)
A * T^4 = 1000 / (1.0 * 5.670373×10-8)
A * T^4 = 17635524153
```

Which means that if we have a 1m2 radiator....

```
T^4 = 17635524153
T = 364.4 degrees Kelvin
```

Converted to Celcius, that's a surface temperature of 91 degrees, which is hot but not crazy. That's a pretty decent cooling loop you've got there, a gradient of 60 degrees - about 3 times that of a typical freezer, but it sounds pretty plausable to me.
Curiously the emissivity and area don't really matter so much because of that `T^4`. If we halve our area to 0.5m2 we only bump our radiators surface temperature to ~140 degrees.

These temperatures aren't too crazy, radiators that work with those sorts of power levels probably exist in various industrial processes.

---

This is assuming that our suit is a perfect black body emitter on it's radiator panels, and ignores several effects:

- First up, the big kicker: convection and airflow would help to cool the suit. This is why cars have radiator fans. This could *dramatically* reduce radiator temperatures. (Unfortunately my knowledge of thermodynamics is pretty poor, so I'm keen to see other peoples answers with better designed cooling systems.)
- Energy absorbed from the sun would add to the energy needed to be dissipated. Here on earth the solar energy at the surface can hit ~700W. Painting your suit white or silver could help with this (but would hurt emissivity)
- This assumes a 100% efficient system. Any energy created by reactors/pumps etc. would need to be handled by the cooling system as well. There's a thing called the coefficient of performance (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_performance ) which implies a heat pump can move ~3x more heat than it consumes, so a heat pump that provided 1Kw cooling would require ~300 watts power.
- That same source suggests that sitting down reduces a humans thermal output to only 100W.

Comment: "(Unfortunately my knowledge of thermodynamics is pretty poor, so I'm keen to see other peoples answers with better designed cooling systems" Suggested reading: [coefficient of performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_performance). Radiative cooling as an approach is... toast.

Comment: May I interest you in some [MathJax](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/607/809)? :)

Comment: T is measured in Kelvin, not in Celsius. So 365 Kelvin is around 93 Celsius.

Comment: @quarague I thought that here the `T` is Temperature in Kelvin above ambient, but on second thoughts you are right. T-above-ambient would imply conductive or convective energy transfer.

Answer (score 4):

Using the sky-radiation scheme from @MikeSerfas answer, it's pretty simple (with abundant energy sources as posited) to make the radiating surface hot enough for black-body to get rid of your heat.  You need Peltier junctions, aka thermocouples, or whatever they develop into over the next hundred centuries.

These work two ways.  The more familiar way, for most people, is to heat one junction while the other is kept cool, to produce a small DC current -- but it's a reversible effect; if you connect the junction pair to a current source, one end will get hot while the other gets cold; in effect, it's a no-moving-parts heat pump.  These are commercially sold for iceless camp coolers and similar, drawing 12 V from an automobile electrical outlet to keep roundly 1/8 cubic meter of insulated box 10-15 °C cooler than the ambient temperature for as long as the power source lasts.

These *could* work without any sort of dedicated radiator; the exterior of the stillsuit would merely have to be (enough) hotter than the ambient temperature of your desert planet to conduct/convect the heat away to the air -- whether that's 40 °C or 60 °C.  Of course, the more temperature differential you need to maintain, the more junctions and the more power are needed.  They might be more efficient, and surely would have a reduced heat/infrared signature, if they had some kind of directed radiator, however.

Comment: "You need Peltier junctions" Good Lord, noooooo... Besides having only a 5% efficiency, the 95% rest of it is **heat**. This is why cascading Peltier elements to obtain lower temperature is doomed to fail for more that 2 stages - the next stage needs to be way larger to dump not only the extracted energy, but also the heat create by the previous stage.

Comment: So I don't suppose there's any likelihood that the efficiency of such a device can be improved in the next *ten thousand years*?

Comment: Give me enough spice and I _just might_ be able to foresee that future :D Until then, `hard-science`  "requires answers backed up by equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, other citations, etc.".

Comment: @ZeissIkon: Peltier junctions, extremely unlikely. (The effect was discovered in the first half of the 19th century. We had plenty of time to explore it.) Another, as yet unknown, solid-state heat pump, maybe.

Comment: We should consider requiring some vetting on hard science questions.  We can't predict ten thousand years of technological advances, all we can say is whether something is possible in 2021 or likely to be within the next decade or so (and even then, only if it's not fusion power).

Comment: @ZeissIkon If we can't say whether it's possible with the hard science we know right now, then the answer is "I don't know," or "not with our current technology." Those are valid answers, and not a reason to stop someone from asking a question in the first place.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi your conclusion is right, but 4-tier Peltier pyramids are used to get CCD camera chips to -70°C.  This needs vacuum insulation, but has been done for over 20 years.  The key difference is that the device to be cooled generates very little heat.

Comment: @ChrisH as usually, a rule is not proper until it gets its own exceptions :) For which there need to be special circumstances that make possible the exceptions possible in the first place.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi of course.  Getting cold is very different to getting cooling power.  Peltiers definitely won't do the job here

Comment: @automaton So, you believe I should delete this answer, since it's not possible to put equations with it to make it look possible?

Comment: @ZeissIkon I never implied anything of the sort. You suggested vetting questions because we can't predict technological advances, and I simply disagree. If the answer is "yes, with hypothetical Peltier junctions of X% efficiency," then show the math with the caveat that those efficiencies aren't possible now. But that's no reason to throw out a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3):

People consume about 2000 kcal/day = 100 W on average. This has to be radiated from a surface of about 1.9 m$^2$, so we need 53 Wm$^{-2}$. The Stefan-Boltzman law requires a temperature difference $T_2-T_1$ such that $\sigma (T_2^4-T_1^4) = 53$, where $\sigma=5.67\times 10^{-8}$ Wm$^{-2}$K$^{-4}$. Hence $T_2^4=T_1^4+53/\sigma$. If the outside temperature is $T_1$ = 50 C = 323 K (a hot day in the Sahara desert), then $T_2$ = 330 K = 57 C.

This calculation ignores lots of other factors like convection, it being cooler at night, etc., but illustrates the point that you don't really require red hot radiator fins to be able to get rid of the small amount of heat a human body generates.

But you do very definitely need active heat pumping to keep the body at a survivable 30 C and the outside of the suit at 57+ C. The maximum efficiency theoretically possible is the Carnot heat cycle, where $1-T_C/T_H=W/Q$. Here, $T_C$ = 303 K and $T_H$ = 330 K so the work needed (per second) divided by the heat energy transferred (per second) is 1-303/330 = 0.08. To transfer 53 Watts we need $0.08\times 53=4.3$ Watts of effort. About 8% of your energy expenditure has to be redirected to keeping cool. Boot pumps driving a compressor seems like a plausible approach.

You need some sort of very high thermal resistance material to separate the inner and outer layers, and then you need heat pumps to pump the heat from the inside through channels in the resistor against the thermal gradient. An extremely good foam insulator (like an aerogel) could have a thermal conductivity of around 0.01 W/m K, so with a temperature difference of 27 K over an area of 1.9 m$^2$ and maximum practical thickness of 1 cm we get a leakage of $0.01\times 27\times 1.9/0.01=51$ W, which is far too large. We're pushing the state of the art, and still need something a factor of 5 better.

Here we have to get a bit speculative, and appeal to future technology and metamaterials. One way to enhance the thermal resistance of a vaccuum is to create many layers. If we have lots of flat opaque membranes separated by vaccuum (with spacers holding them apart strong enough to withstand the pressure and sparsely enough for their contribution to conductivity to be ignored) then heat can only transfer from each membrane to the next by radiation. If the power conducted through the material is $p$ then each membrane must radiate $p$ units of power each way more than the previous one. The membranes radiate $p_0+p$, $p_0+2p$, $p_0+3p$, $p_0+4p$, ... $p_0+np$ units from each side. Take the $p_0+3p$ membrane - it radiates a total of $2p_0+6p$ units of power from its two sides towards its neighbours, and receives $2p_0+2p+4p=2p_0+6p$ from its two neighbours in return, and is thus in equilibrium. In the gap between any pair of membranes, there is $p_0+kp$ units moving one way and $p_0+(k+1)p$ units in the other direction, giving a net transfer of $p$ units. This yields an insulator far more effective than a single vaccuum gap.

Of course, if you suppose the desert is generally cooler than that (as most deserts on Earth are) then the problem goes away. Descriptions of Arrakis emphasise the extreme dryness, not the heat. A desert can be quite cool, and still deadly for lack of water.

Answer (score 1):

**It's a matter of creating particles...**

We need to carry the entropy away somehow.  So we want to make some low-energy particles and send it away.  Specifically, we want a surface with an [emissivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity) greater than 1, or at least, which *acts* like it has an emissivity greater than 1.

For example...

- We create "ommatidia", deep cavities with an emitting membrane that faces upward toward the desert sky.  They receive little infrared radiation in that direction, so *if* we could increase the rate at which photons are radiated (or absorbed - I'm not going to require irreversibility here) then we could get rid of all the heat we wanted.  Question is ... is there any way, with all that Dune technology, to get our photon count well above what a black body would produce?
- We do neutrino pair production.  Some neutrinos are very, very low in mass, and if we use some free energy to make them out of nothing, then they will carry away some heat with no additional charge.  Can Dune tech make neutrinos?

Any other hypothetical particle you can mine from the books might similarly have such a function.

**Alternatively...**
You can use your spice-induced prescience to pick the universe where all the random transfers of heat from one particle to another happen to move away from you. :)

Comment: Neutrinos et al are the only "magic" cooling option that can keep an object cooler than it's surroundings passively and indefinitely without violating thermodynamics. Too bad no known material gets *anywhere* near the needed absorption cross-section for sub-eV neutrino energies.

Comment: @KevinKostlan see this [Nature paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature13883).  more work has been done since then, but this is the group I saw give a keynote talk ata  conference.   Radiative cooling can be done to space with materials that are very reflective at wavelengths the atmosphere radiates, but emit well at other wavelengths that go straight out to space.  So it's very much a non-black body, but behaves like one at some wavelength ranges. The sun fills very little of the sky in angular terms so isn't major consideration.

Comment: ... these coatings can also be visible-transparent, so there's work on applying them to cool solar panels (which get less efficient and less robust when hot).  It's not good enough yet, but not so very far from reality (needs to face the sky for best effect, so a *very* broad-brimmed hat!)

Comment: @ChrisH Okay, *that* is pretty much the answer to this question.  I missed that paper, but *"we experimentally demonstrate radiative cooling to nearly 5 degrees Celsius below the ambient air temperature under direct sunlight..."*  Just by applying a coating?

Comment: @MikeSerfas it's not yet efficient enough, and it's not like painting it on - in fact rather a difficult process.  (I have to admit I was sceptical at first, even hearing it at a reputable scientific conference, but it's mainly a counterintuitive  application of radiative and atmospheric physics, with some well-established optical production techniques.  The Fremen would need a cleanroom with some pretty sophisticated kit in their caves to produce the material.

Comment: ... so the particles are photons, but rather than *angular* selectivity as you propose, we use *wavelength* selectivity and avoid the need to reach unphysical emissivity or pump heat into a very hot radiator

Comment: At least "not yet efficient enough" is OK for sci-fi. Fudge factors: 1. Combine angular with wavelength selectivity with microstructures. 2. Bone-dry air of dune makes it work better than on earth, and the tech would be more advanced. 3. Maybe the desert is not quite as hot as Sahara, and/or they usually go inside in the heat of the day. 4. Maybe they can push their body temp to 40C with training or genetics, and it naturally drops to 35C at night, giving 5C of "storage".